# JSON deserialization question

Tags: c#, json

I have written a JSON serializer using JavaScriptSerializer. I am wondering when the server add some property to the JSON object, will my serializer still work?

Comment: I think it would benefit everyone and allow us to give you a faster answer if you can clarify "when the server add some property to the JSON object" and "I have written a JSON Serializer". Can you share some code?

Comment: I just did a normal json serialization/deserialization using JavaScriptSerializer, nothing special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Forward compatible data contracts on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx

If you use the `DataContractSerializer` with `IExtensibleDataObject` as shown in that article you can implement forward compatible serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Thanks. Particularly, do you think JavaScriptSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer implement this feature?

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer has this capability.